# "to fink meself lucky"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, eye-dialect

> "I was selling in Diagon Alley an' she come up to me an' asks if I've got a licence for trading in magical artefacts. Bleedin' snoop. She was gonna fine me, but she took a fancy to the locket an' told me she'd take it and let me off that time an' **to fink meself lucky**."
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I figure 'fink' is a dialect word for 'think' - *to think myself lucky*. But the use of 'to' confused me too. I think 'to' shouldn't be there. ***...let me off that time an' fink meself lucky*** looks more correct to me.

What's the correct way to understand it?

Comment: All the highlighted elements of *...she took a fancy to the locket an' [**she**] told me she'd take it and [**she'd**] let me off that time an' [**she told me**] to fink meself lucky* are "deleted" (because they're ***predictable repeated elements***). Does that make it clearer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> She […] told me she'd take it and let me off that time an' to fink meself lucky.

My reading is that

- she told me she'd take it and let me off that time, and
- she told me to think myself lucky.

Essentially, she said, "You're lucky that I'm allowing you to merely give me that locket, instead of making you pay a fine."

Comment: Yes. "told me _something_ and [told me] to think myself lucky"